# Variables from different class - php

Tags: php, oop

okey so here is my structure.

one.php two.php three.php

one.php includes both two.php and three.php

two.php is

```
class two {
  function test(){  $var ='gello'; }}
```

three.php is

```
class three {
function testt(){  $var ='hello'; }}
```

So how could i use the $var variable of two.php in three.php ?

in one.php i can do that by

```
 $one = new two(); 
 $one->var;
```

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome and try please to format your code better.

Comment: Can you not just do the same thing? As long as two.php is included before three.php, why wouldn't it work? What did you get when you tried doing that?

Comment: In both these cases, `$var` is _local_ to the functions `test(), testt()`.  Class properties would use `$this->var`

Comment: oh wait, no. you'd have to instantiate a `$twoo = new two()` and pass `$twoo` as an argument to a newly-instantiated `three`'s method or something... no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define variable outiside the function

When you write inside function, only the function know who are `$var` and show te correct value.

```
class two {
    public $var = 'foo';

    function setVar($var = 'foo') {
        $this->var = $var;
    }
}

class three {
    function test() {
        $two = new two();
        echo($two->var); // Show 'foo'

        $two->setVar('bar');
        echo($two->var); // Show 'bar'
    }
}

// Result 'foo'
$one = new two();
echo($one->var);

// Result 'fooz'
$one->setVar('fooz');
echo($one->var);

// Result 'foo' and 'bar'
$three = new three();
$three->test();
```